# Prolog Database Recording

Tags: prolog, factorial, memoization, prolog-tabling

I have this factorial predicate.

```
fact(0, 1).
fact(N, F) :- N > 0, 
        N1 is N-1,
        fact(N1, F1),
        F is F1 * N.
```

How do I change this predicate such that every time a query is issued, the result of the calculation is stored in the database? New queries should use then the stored results if available.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking for. Stored in what  database? What do you want to do with the results?

Comment: I want to do this by using assertz in prolog.                                         result(N,FF):- assertz(fact(N,FF)). <-  this doesnt work but it should be similar to this. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is generally called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), but is referred to as tabling in the context of Prolog. Conveniently, there is a library for this called [tabling](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling) for SWI Prolog.

```
:- use_module(library(tabling)).
:- table fact/2.

fact(0, 1).
fact(N, F) :- N > 0,
              N1 is N-1,
              fact(N1, F1),
              F is F1 * N.
```

You can verify that the memoization works by running `trace` before your calls to `fact`. Note that the two `:-` lines are called directives and are run by the compiler, so running them in a repl will not work.

#### Edit

If you don't want to use the tabling library, you can accomplish this with [asserta](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=asserta/1). This will insert a fact at the top of the database, as if you had entered it into the file yourself.

```
fact(0, 1).
fact(N, F) :-
              N > 0,
              N1 is N-1,
              fact(N1, F1),
              F is F1 * N,
              asserta(fact(N, F)).
```

Prolog will see the new predicate first and will use it instead of recomputing your factorial. Once again, you can check this by tracing.

Comment: I want to do this by using assertz in prolog.                                               result(N,FF):- assertz(fact(N,FF)).  <- this doesnt work but it should be similar to this. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As jcolemang said, what you want is tabling/memoization. While there are indeed libraries which is the recommended and efficient (not just time-wise, but mainly performance-wise) way of doing things, it is understandable that you may want to implement it on your own.

It is possible to use assert to add [dynamic](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic/1) facts in the prolog database, but you'll need to declare them as such, by having `:-dynamic(fact)` in the file which will allow you to add/remove facts.

However, there's a performance penalty in doing that. An alternative would be to have a lookup table/cache that will be persisted across calls. The dictionary could be stored using [global mutable variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar) (yikes!), which are more efficient than using dynamic facts. As always, it's a good idea to minimize the code that uses variables/side-effects directly - in your factorial example, you could simply have a wrapper predicate that fetches the dictionary and puts it back at the end of the call e.g.

```
factorial(N, F):-
get_global_dict(D),
real_factorial(N, F, D, DF),
store_global_dict(DF).
```